# How to set color to html attribute title value

Tags: html, css

Based on my title attribute I need to change color of my cell inside table

Consider below example whenever my title value says *WHO* - I need to change color of my `<p> element` to RED

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p><abbr title="WHO">WHO</abbr> was founded in    1948.</p>
        <p><abbr title="WHO">World People</abbr> was founded in    1948.</p>
        <p title="Free Web tutorials">W3Schools.com</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Based on the current markup you provided, this would not be possible with just CSS. You would either need to modify your markup (to take advantage of a general sibling-type selector) or use JavaScript.

Comment: You are after the mythical CSS parent selector, at this point in time, no such creature exists

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you cannot achieve what you're trying to do with HTML and CSS alone. But if you use JavaScript or jQuery you can easily add colors to the P tag dynamically base on abbr title attribute value.

```js
$(function() {
 $("p").has("abbr[title='WHO']").css("color", "red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><abbr title="WHO">WHO</abbr> was founded in    1948.</p>
<p><abbr title="WHO">World People</abbr> was founded in    1948.</p>
<p><abbr title="WHEN">Sample</abbr> not in red.</p>
```

Comment: why jquery, we dont need jquery for every  task  ?

Comment: @NullPoiиteя this is a solution suggestion based on the markup provided in the OP :)

Answer (score 0):

Your title is an attribute inside the abbr in the paragraph so you can access it by using the following ways:

1.You can do it with **CSS** like:

```
p > abbr[title="WHO"]{
    color: rgb(255,0,0);
}
```

Here > will select the child element.
 Tested on [jsfiddle.net/3gLcw0mt/](https://jsfiddle.net/3gLcw0mt/)

2.Or you can do It with Jquery
***Jquery:***

```
$("p").has("abbr[title='WHO']").css("color", "rgb(255,0,0)");
```

Here first, we have selected the `p` tag then checking the attributes inside it. `.css()` will allow you to change the value of any CSS property using Jquery

and don't forget to include the Jquery CDN to your file:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
p < abbr[title="who"] {
     * your styling *
}
```

The < here is a selector and the direction defines the element to be selected. In this case every p element which has a child element abbr with the title "who" will be selected. For more info Google css parent and child selectors

- Updating my ans *

The above will not work, coz there is no parent selector. But you can still select the child elements using this >. apologize for misleading with my answer.
https://jsfiddle.net/fxkbtmjc/

Comment: Not sure where you came up with _"The < here is a selector and the direction defines the element to be selected. In this case every p element which has a child element abbr with the title "who" will be selected. For more info Google css parent and child selectors"_ but it's wrong. There is no parent or "direction" selector yet. The direct descendant selector is a real thing `>` though, but not `<`

Comment: Well I've tired it few times and haven't faced any problems. Maybe my browser versions supported I guess. I'll check again and get back to you on this. Thanks for the info

Comment: Yeah you should check on that and get back to us. Maybe with some documentation and examples.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/

Comment: @j08691 when one doesnt remember what once learned, this `<` already exists LOL

Comment: Nope: http://jsfiddle.net/13krq7w8/ . Tested Chrome 67, Firefox 60,  Edge 42, IE 11. All windows. Please at least test your solutions or provide completed examples.

Comment: Your answer is wrong.

Comment: @j08691 yes you are right! the > selector works but not the < selector. I have been using > this for a while and I thot this < will also work. My bad, I apologize for my mistake and thanks for pointing it out.